# Fedora 19 can no longer see eth0

Tags: networking, internet, fedora

I've been using this Fedora 19 system that I installed myself. It's running on some really old hardware - nothing but a motherboard, CPU, RAM, and HDDs. No network cards, no graphics cards, sound cards, nothing. No 3rd party drivers either - I relied completely on Fedora to make everything work out of the box, and so far, everything has (even the network).

Until someone turned it off (Who turns off a server?).

Upon booting, the motherboard / BIOS was warning me about resetting values back to defaults, which probably has something to do with the dead motherboard battery. Notably, the date went back to January 1, 2006.

Since this has never been a problem before, I paid it no mind, loaded up the default values (via F1), and continued on my merry way.

Upon getting to the desktop, however, I can't see the usual eth0 anymore. Can't connect to the internet, either.

**What I tried:**

- Typing in `ifconfig` in the CLI gets me only `lo`.
- `ifconfig eth0` gets me an `error fetching interface information: device not found.`
- Pinging anything gets me a `Network unreachable`. I can see an eth0 in Network management, but this is probably just the stored configuration.

[Link](http://snk.to/f-c7c8vfs9) to results of `lspci` (.txt file, from FileSnack)

**The Hardware:**

- Asrock 775i65G [more info](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/775i65G/)
- Intel Celeron CPU 2.66Ghz

I'm not much of a Linux person, so I'm afraid that's all I have. What can I do to remedy this?

Comment: What does write `ifconfig eth0`? Which messages related to networking do you have in `dmesg`? You also did not describe the network card/interface. Which is it? Is it integrated or as a card? Is there a related setting in the BIOS setup (deactivation of the onboard port, IRQ settings...)?

Comment: My apologies, I did not know about those commands. I've updated my question with regards to `ifconfig eth0`, but I'm not sure what to look for in `dmesg`. And no, there were no motherboard configurations, other than date/time. This is as bone stock as it can be.

Comment: Relevant part of `dmesg` could be in `dmesg | grep -iE 'net|nic|eth|irq|msi'`. You can probably paste the complete filtered output if you do not know what to look for. --- I have never seen a BIOS with only date/time setting. Which one is it? --- To see which network card you have you will probably need to open the computer and/or consult the documentation. Please send the name and model of the network card and of the motherboard.

Comment: also, does `ifconfig -a` display more than just `lo` ?

Comment: The command returned mostly `NET: Registered protocol family` and such. The motherboard is an Asrock 775i65g, with a Realtek PCI LAN 8101L - as for my comment about the configuration, sorry if I didn't make it clear, but I meant that I did not modify any BIOS setting other than the date/time - this was because it was working fine before.

Comment: @Levans, no, `ifconfig -a` displays only `lo`.

Comment: what about `lspci |grep -i 'eth'` ? Also maybe `modprobe -l |grep  'drivers/net'`

Comment: @Kwaio `lspci Igrep -i 'eth'` doesn't return anything. The `modprobe` one tells me that the `-l` isn't a valid option.

Comment: Paste up the output of lspci, don't use grep.

Comment: @Lawrence, modified the question. Link for text file is here: http://snk.to/f-c7c8vfs9

Comment: Judging from the output of lspci, I would say the ethernet adapter has died.

Comment: Oh.... crap. That pretty much means no 'yum install anything', right?